# Removing Default Input Submit Button

Tags: html, css

I am currently having problems with my input button it has a button over the button i created that i don't want but it wont disappear.

[The problem showing in this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LyCz.png)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="btn waves-effect waves-light col s12" tabindex="5" style="">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
         <p class="margin center medium-small sign-up">Already have an account? <a href="login.html">Login</a></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: a button over the button? can u show us?

Comment: On your image, is it the _Register_ button that you want to make disappear ? ... just remove the input

Comment: My css is the green button but for some reason that grey button appears that i want to disable so that my green button works

Answer (score 0):

It should disappear if you add `border: 0; background: 0;` to your CSS for the button.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="btn waves-effect waves-light col s12" tabindex="5" style="border: 0; background: 0;">
```

And the default box should be gone!

Comment: Thanks, the info you gave me was enough for me to know what to do, I needed to delete part of my class for it work for some reason. Thanks